# After I downloaded Adblock plus on my computer, ads still popped up on youtube? What gives?

Tags: web-application

I downloaded Adblock plus on my computer, then went back to youtube (which was playing Vivaldi concertos), and all the ads were yet there.  What gives?  Is Adblock plus authentic?

Comment: what is the part that is linked to the topi **security**? The question about if Adblick plus is authentic? If so I suggest you give more insights regarding the way that you acquired that software... If you simple tell that you download something it is hard to answer if it is authentic or not. There is any chance it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Adblock plus takes money from sites to allow "acceptable ads".  It is a recent change to the policy and it is how Adblock plus pays for the product.

Users can still turn them off.  The reddit link below has some instructions.

http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/06/google-and-others-reportedly-pay-adblock-plus-to-show-you-ads-anyway/

http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1upvgv/adblock_isnt_blocking_ads_in_youtube_videos/

Answer (score 0):

There is also an add-on in firefox called [no-script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) which does well at blocking ads and third party scripts such as google syndication and analytics as well as the malicious scripts. Hope this helps